# Will a VPN allow Remote Desktop to all machines on network?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, vpn

If I setup a XP-Pro VPN server and a user logs into it from outside the LAN, can they Remote Desktop to any of the machines on the network?

What are the security concerns with this setup?

All machines are XP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A VPN is like being on the same network. As long as the VPN connection is secure, and the Remote Desktop on each of the machines are secure, you should be ok.

Comment: How do you make an XP VPN connection secure?

Comment: Make sure you're using the strongest authentication and encryption possible. Make sure to use firewall, etc.